# Using MusicKit JS from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, apple-musickit

MusicKit JS is a javascript library that allows third-party developers to build web clients for apple music. This allows access to the otherwise fully-closed apple music ecosystem.

I am wondering if there is a way to use this library from nodejs to build a command-line application that can play songs from apple music, theoretically on any operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and unfortunately this is not possible with MusicKitJs right now. The library depends pretty heavily on browser APIs so it just breaks in the Node JS environment